# visual studio output window not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm on a mac and using Visual Studio Community 2017 and the output window doesn't come up when I run the program, I don't know how to reset the settings if that's even possible, I don't think I have touched any settings but something obviously happened. I deleted and reinstalled Visual Studio but it still didn't work.

[image: Visual Studio Community 2017 Screenshot]

Comment: what output window are you talking about?

Answer (score 14):

In the visual studio GUI, go to `Window>Reset Window Layout`. This should do it!

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to toggle the Output window by going to `View > Output Window`. If it still doesn't appear, then try `Window > Reset Window Layout`.

Comment: There is no Output Window Option in View for me and there is no Reset Window Layout in Window for me, I'm on Mac and on Visual Studio Community 2017, also CTRL ALT O doesn't work... I'm so confused...

Comment: So, question: are you looking for the output window which can show build output and the like, or the console window which appears with console based applications?

Comment: I think i mean the console window because I'm doing a console application, sorry for not being clear, I'm relatively new to this, I'm used to programming in python where there was only one input window and one output window and that was it, this is a lot more complicated so I'm trying to learn but it's just weird that it was working and now all of a sudden it's not. But I think it's the console window that isn't working but i don't know why and what to do.

Comment: Ah, ok! Not a problem, glad to see you're trying to take the plunge!

Now, I come from a windows development background, so I'm flying a little blind. What kind of a project did you create when you started this? Or, if you were to start over, could you describe the template you select if any, or if you are following a guide?

Comment: Also, could you post your code sample you're trying to run?

Comment: I am on a console project template, and I've been trying to start new ones but it still doesn't work.

Comment: When I start a new console project with the basic hello world code that's already there it still doesn't work so I'm pretty sure it's not because of the code because the hello world code was working before until yesterday

Comment: At the end of your code, do you have a line like `Console.ReadLine();`? If so, does your code appear to run and continue forever, or does it run and then immediately quit? Updating your original post with sample code will help a lot.

Comment: I have Console.Readline(); in my code and I have tried it on a few different projects but it's the same with all of them. It seems like it runs and then quits and I get this error: Debugger operation failed. ScriptError: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent timed out.

Comment: Can you add a photo of your interface @MS?

Comment: I uploaded a photo, this is what it looks like and it’s on the hello world program that you get when you start a console project but it looks the same everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or go to VIEW -> Output

Comment: Sorry, I down vote by mistake. This works after `Window>Reset Window Layout`.

Comment: Screenshot shows that it's clearly on Mac. Ctrl Alt don't exist on the mac

Answer (score 2):

I'm on windows and none of the solutions above worked for me. I have 4 monitors and it turned out my output window had moved off the screen. Turning off 3 of the monitors so windows auto-adjust got it back for me.

Comment: I disagree with the "not an answer" close votes. Disabling multiple monitors is in fact an answer to this issue.

Comment: I had the issue described by the title of the post 'visual studio output window not showing' though the details varied, the solutions provided here were appropriate for my problem but didn't work. So I posted what did work for me, granted it's not a full solution to the op's question but someone else with the same problem as me may find themselves here so maybe what I said will help. Though, is it more appropriate to ask a separate question in this case? I could also see that being marked as duplicate.